# Cant clear the cache on my symfony2 website

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

When I perform this action:

```
sudo php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

I get this error:

```
[ErrorException]
  Warning: rename(/var/www/mysite.co.uk/app/cache/prod,/var/www/mysite.co.uk/app/cache/prod_old): Directory not empty in /var/www/mysite.co.uk/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php line 74
```

Can anybody help?  Im tempted to manually delete all the files in `/cache/prod` but Im concerned this may cause more problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you an existing `/var/www/mysite.co.uk/app/cache/prod_old` directory?

You can delete manually the `cache/prod` to force cache cleaning.

Comment: Within my cache folder I see: /dev, /prod, /prod_new, /prod_old. Do you mean delete the entire content of the /prod folder or delete the folder itself?

Comment: I think your exception is thrown because of the presence of the `/var/www/mysite.co.uk/app/cache/prod_old`, can you delete it and re launch the `sudo php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` command. If it does not work, delete the folder `cache/prod` manually.

Comment: I removed prod_old and re-ran the cache:clear command. That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: well, but the user mentioned that he has also /dev should that not be deleted? 
and second, this command (php app/console cache:clear --env=prod brakes the access rights in that folder - makes the root owner and makes it readable/writable for every user)

Answer (score 9):

Just clear cache manually by `rm -Rf app/cache/*`.

After that you should warm up cache via `php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod`

Note, users will lose the session if you didn't configure `session: save_path` in `config.yml`.